# How to create a date formatted cell with correct date using title of sheet plus text in a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to figure out if this is even possible:

All cells are in 'General' format. So it's all strings, I think.

A1=blank, B1=6, C1=7, D1=10, E1=11, F1=12, G1=13, H1=16 etc (note the gaps in the sequence)

Sheet name is "May 2013"

I need to get row 1, with the exception of A1, to be in date format (dd/mm/yy), showing the date that is assembled from the sheet's name and the day of the month in the 1st row.

So, cell B1 would wind up in 'date' format while displaying 6/5/13.

TIA. This is killing me!

Comment: I assume you mean 6/5/13. How is it "killing" you, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried searching. Searched for a number of phrases that I thought would describe this process. Had no luck. I'm a raw rookie at VBA, so I don't even know what to call this process of pulling the month out of the sheet name. It's 'killing me' in the sense that I really need to accomplish the task but I feel unable to find the solution myself.
And yeah, 6/5/13. Will edit my question.

Comment: Oh, I've just realised you gave me my first down-vote.
Thanks.
Sorry my question isn't up to snuff. 
I figured that including my past Google efforts wasn't meaningful to the question, and that my ignorance level (VBA newbie) would be self-evident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following user-defined function (UDF) in a Module:

```
Function GetSheetDate(rng As Range) As Date
    Dim dtTemp As Date

    dtTemp = DateValue(rng.Range("A1").Value & " " & rng.Parent.Name)
    GetSheetDate = dtTemp
End Function
```

Then enter `=GetSheetDate(B1)` in a cell. Format this cell as a date and then copy this formula to the right.

Comment: Ah-hA!
OK, so you pull the name out with this *.Parent.Name* call, which appears to return a string (right? because you didn't have to convert it to feed it to DateValue?)

There are too many sheets to do it manually by dragging formulas on cells.

So, would this same method work but in a Sub?
Say, if I did this:

Make a range based on which cells are supposed to be the dates.
Then cycle through the cells in that range, first pulling that sheet name up and concatenating it with the day number, and then setting the cell format to DDMMYY.
Move to next cell in range, etc.
Then move to next sheet.

Comment: Yes, you've described it well :)

Comment: Got it all to work except the rotating through sheets part. But still, awesome info and code. Thanks again!